# printDialog PageSize on Linux

Tags: java, printdialog

While working on Windows on Linux the print process doesn't use the page size that is shown in the printDialog. It always uses the size that is set in the OS printer settings. Has anybody also observed this behaviour. I consider writing a bug report about it.

Answer (score 0):

I've only dealt with C# `PrintDialog`, so I could be wrong, but the `PrintDialog` retrieves all of its information from the printer's driver.  It is likely that the driver installed on the Linux machine is being used when querying printer settings, meaning the driver returns different values when queried from a Linux machine vs. a Windows machine.